# Is it possible to bind this in bluebird map?

Tags: node.js, bluebird

So I've tried to write up an example as best I could of what I'm trying to do, this isn't a very practical example but I tried to simplify it, but I feel like I may have complicated this in trying to make an example.

```js
class add {
  constructor(baseValue) {
    this.base = baseValue;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this);
    });
  }
  addBase(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this.base + num);
    });
  }
}

const values = [1,2,3,4,5];

Promise.try(() => {
  return new add(5);
}).then((add) => {
  // we want to find if a 5 exists in the results
  const addPromise = Promise.resolve(values).map(add.addBase, {concurrency: 1});
  return Promise.try(() => {
    return addPromise;
  }).then((results) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      if(results[i] === 10) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    // doesn't exist
    return null;
  });
}).then((result) => {
  if(result === null) {
    console.log('10 does not exist');
  } else {
    console.log('10 is at position ' + result);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

If you run this you'll get an error that you can't get base of undefined, this is because of the mapping in bluebird. `const addPromise = Promise.resolve(values).map(add.addBase, {concurrency: 1});` Is there a way on this line to bind the add object to `this` when making these calls?

Comment: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a little simpler than you're making it I think. You are passing the raw function into `map()`, but you should probably be passing an arrow function instead. Consider this simple class and code that tries to use `map()` by passing `add()`:

```js
class Test{
    constructor(n) {
        this.n = n
    }
    add(k) {
        return this.n + k
    }
}
let t = new Test(10)
let arr = [1, 2, 3]

// error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.n')
arr.map(t.add)
```

This throws an error because map isn't calling `add()` from the object, it just thinks it's a function. An easy fix is to call map like this:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(n) {
    this.n = n
  }
  add(k) {
    return this.n + k
  }
}
let t = new Test(10)

let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let mapped = arr.map((n) => t.add(n))
console.log(mapped)
```

You could also use:

```
let mapped = arr.map(t.add.bind(t))
```

but to me that's harder to read and understand quickly. I'm not sure what's going on with all the immediately resolved promises in your code, but changing the way you call `map()` makes that error go away. (there's another error later where you reference `i` that's not in scope.)

Comment: All of the immediately resolved promises was me attempting to make this case as close to my issue as possible, those would normally be calls that require time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much answered your own question…

```js
class add {
  constructor(baseValue) {
    this.base = baseValue;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this);
    });
  }
  addBase(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this.base + num);
    });
  }
}

const values = [1,2,3,4,5];

Promise.try(() => {
  return new add(5);
}).then((add) => {
  // we want to find if a 5 exists in the results
  const addPromise = Promise.resolve(values).map(add.addBase.bind(add), {concurrency: 1});
  return Promise.try(() => {
    return addPromise;
  }).then((results) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      if(results[i] === 10) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    // doesn't exist
    return null;
  });
}).then((result) => {
  if(result === null) {
    console.log('10 does not exist');
  } else {
    console.log('10 is at position ' + result);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```